# Esta aplicación no es compatible con tu dispositivo. Google Play

Tags: google-play

Tengo un problema al subir una pequeña aplicación para buscar en los contáctos del teléfono.

He subido otras app al google play sin problemas, pero en esta en concreto me da este error, y no tengo forma de saber el error, ¿existe alguna herramienta donde diga el error exacto por el cual no es compatible?.

Desde Google Play Console, me dice dispositivos admitidos: 15.204
La aplicación no es de pago.
En la 2ª versión puse : android:supportsRtl="false"   ,  pero no funcionó.
En la 3ª versión he añadido al manifest el uses-feature, pero no ha funcionado tampoco.

No sé qué más modificar, pero desde la consola de google podrían tener alguna herramienta para analizar estos problemas...

---

*****   este es el manifest    ************

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.castalia.telefono">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_telefono"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_telefono"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".WidgetControl" android:label="Agenda Castalia">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.castalia.telefono.ACTUALIZAR_WIDGET"/>
            <action android:name="com.castalia.telefono.CLICK_WIDGET"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>



        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/rc_widget_wprovider" />
    </receiver>

</application>
```

****** build.gradle (app)   *****

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.castalia.telefono"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 3
    versionName "3.20.03gp"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Pego el enlace directo de la aplicación en Google Play: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.castalia.telefono

[image: mensaje de pantalla Google Play]

Comment: La versión 29 es Android 10. ¿Tienes Android 10 en alguno de tus terminales?

Comment: No tengo android 10, pero creo que acabo de encontrar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de solucionar el problema.
En el apartado de distribución de la aplicación (consola de google play), existe una opción de: Google Play administrado.
Por error (o simple desconocimiento), lo había marcado en esta app.
Al parecer Google presentaba el error de dispositivo no compatible, pero en realidad todo venía por esta configuración. 
Dejo imágen de la pantalla, para que si a alguien le ocurre lo mismo lo pueda solventar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]